# A Pun or Not a Pun

Tags: puns, terms-of-venery

If you say, "hello dear" to a person dressed as a deer is it a pun? I think it is a pun, but my friend argues that it is not.

Comment: Yes, but if the same person is dressed as an ostrich, "Hello dear" just doesn't work!

Comment: It's [an attempt, at least, at] a joke. It involves wordplay (dear // deer). It's a pun.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.

Comment: Another question about the meaning of the word "pun": [Can the unexpected validity of the literal meaning of a phrase on top of the usual figurative sense be considered a pun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412805) It might help people write better answers if you edit this post to add more explanation of why your friend argues that it is not a pun.

Comment: I'd add the *endearment* tag, but I don't want to touch @tchrist 's tag edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the unexpected validity of the literal meaning of a phrase on top of the usual figurative sense be considered a pun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412805/can-the-unexpected-validity-of-the-literal-meaning-of-a-phrase-on-top-of-the-usu)